# KineticJs - When dynamically creating rect, the rect behind it drags by itself

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

In kineticjs I am creating dynamic rectangles that are draggable. However when I create a new rectangle, the rectangle behind it automatically drags. I dont want this to happen.

You can see the behaviour in demo at http://jsfiddle.net/sandeepy02/8kGVD/12/

Step 1: Choose "create  rectangle" and create rectangles.
Step 2: Choose "Move rectangle" and move the rectangles.
Step 3: Choose "create  rectangle" and create rectangles. This causes the rectangles previously created to also move. This is unwanted.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
function valButton(radios) {
    var btn = document.getElementsByName(radios);
    var cnt = -1;
    for (var i = btn.length - 1; i > -1; i--) {
        if (btn[i].checked) {
            cnt = i;
            i = -1;
        }
    }
    if (cnt > -1) return btn[cnt].value;
    else return null;
}

window.onload = function() {
    layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
    stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container: "container",
        width: 320,
        height: 320
    });
    background = new Kinetic.Rect({
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        width: stage.getWidth(),
        height: stage.getHeight(),
        fill: "white"
    });


    layer.add(background);
    stage.add(layer);

    moving = false;

    stage.on("mousedown touchstart", function() {
        var btnName = valButton("group2");
        if (btnName == "1") {
            if (moving) {
                moving = false;
                layer.draw();
            } else {
                var mousePos = stage.getMousePosition();
                rect = new Kinetic.Rect({
                    x: 22,
                    y: 7,
                    width: 0,
                    height: 0,
                    fill: 'red',
                    stroke: 'black',
                    strokeWidth: 4,
                    draggable: true
                });
                layer.add(rect);
                //start point and end point are the same
                rect.setX(mousePos.x);
                rect.setY(mousePos.y);
                rect.setWidth(0);
                rect.setHeight(0);
                moving = true;
                layer.drawScene();
            }
        }
        document.all.text.innerText = btnName +" "+moving;

    }); //end of mousedown
    stage.on("mousemove touchmove", function() {
        var btnName = valButton("group2");
        if (btnName == "1") {
            if (moving) {
                var mousePos = stage.getMousePosition();
                var x = mousePos.x;
                var y = mousePos.y;
                rect.setWidth(mousePos.x - rect.getX());
                rect.setHeight(mousePos.y - rect.getY());
                moving = true;
                layer.drawScene();
            }
        }
        else if (btnName == "3") {
            layer.draw();
        }
        document.all.text.innerText = btnName +" "+moving;
    }); //end of mousemove
    stage.on("mouseup touchend", function() {
        var btnName = valButton("group2");
        if (btnName == "1") {
            moving = false;
        }
        document.all.text.innerText = btnName +" "+moving;
    }); //end of mouseup
};
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <h2>Toggle buttons</h2>
<div class="toggle-btn-grp">
    <label onclick="" class="toggle-btn"><input type="radio" value="1" name="group2"/> Create Rectangle</label>
    <label onclick="" class="toggle-btn"><input type="radio" value="3" name="group2"/>Move Rectangle</label>
</div>

        <div id="container" ></div>
                <div id="text" >abc</div>

    </body>
</html>​
```

Comment: The fiddle works for me. Only one rectangle ever moves, even if I drag the overlap.

Comment: Design note: try always bringing the dragged rectangle into the foreground (and keeping it there when drag stops?).

Comment: Note that it's not exactly performant in Firefox (but works in Chrome). Cannot reproduce in either.

Comment: More exactly, firefox does not seem to fire `mousemove` when dragging. Try listening to `mousedrag` as well?

Comment: Jan it works only if you are creating rectangles at the initial stage. But if you create rectangles and then choose the "move" option and move a rectangle (moving is a must) and then again click on "create rectangle", the creation of new rectangles will drag the previous rectangles too. The issue occurs in chrome too.

Comment: is the final rectangle that you are creating on top of the previously created rectangle?

Comment: It is. Do you want it to be inside the rectangle? Around the rectangle?

Comment: Finally managed to reproduce.

Comment: great! One way I could think was to disable drag for all the elements while I am creating a new rectangle - but I am not sure if that efficient and moreover I do not know how to do it.

Comment: You should debug the state of the `moving` flag. I think it's set when it shouldn't.

Comment: note that setting `moving = true` from within a block conditioned by `if(moving)` is redundant. The flag is already set at this point.

Comment: Comments (and descriptive button values) would be nice.

Comment: If movement is managed by kineticJS, then you have to disable it while dragging. I don't think this would be inefficient.

Comment: Thanks Jan - actually i debugged the moving flag before posting the message - did not get any error in that. Modified the button to be more descriptive flag status at http://jsfiddle.net/sandeepy02/8kGVD/12/

Comment: but how to go about setting all shapes value as draggable and not draggable?

Comment: That's what I meant. Is it possible otherwise?

Comment: Could it be that you release the mousebutton outside the canvas? I can't reproduce the  'error' if i do all the mouseevents inside the canvas but it's quite easy if you draw a new rect and draw it to the edge of the canvas.

Comment: I tried everything - not able to correct this behaviour. Anyways I think I will try fabricjs or Easeljs. Meanwhile any solution is most welcome

Comment: Add the move listener (i.e. case when move radio button is selected) only to the rect objects that you create instead of stage.

Comment: Ani: Havent understood how it will work. I am a newbie :) .Can you please modify my code where you expect the changes. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your updated function to fix the problem -

```
    stage.on("mousedown touchstart", function() {
    var btnName = valButton("group2");
    if (btnName == "Create") {
        if (moving) {
            moving = false;
            layer.draw();
        } else {
            var mousePos = stage.getMousePosition();
            rect = new Kinetic.Rect({
                x: 0,
                y: 0,
                width: 0,
                height: 0,
                fill: 'red',
                stroke: 'black',
                strokeWidth: 4,
                draggable: true
            });
            layer.add(rect);
            //start point and end point are the same
            rect.setX(mousePos.x);
            rect.setY(mousePos.y);
            rect.setWidth(0);
            rect.setHeight(0);
            moving = true;
            rect.on("mousemove touchmove", function() {
                var btnName = valButton("group2");
                if (btnName == "Create") {
                    this.setDraggable(false);
                }
                else if (btnName == "Move") {
                    this.setDraggable(true);
                }
                document.all.text.innerText = btnName +" rect move MovingFlag: "+moving;
            }); //end of rect mousemove
            layer.drawScene();
        }
    }
    document.all.text.innerText = btnName +" MovingFlag: "+moving;

}); //end of mousedown
```