# object property to dynamically change with the value of assigned variable

Tags: javascript, kineticjs, javascript-objects

This may turn out to be a very basic question as I am a newbie. I am creating an object from a constructor. I want one of the properties of object to be linked to a variable. So if variable value changes, the property's value should also change.

Example: I am working on kineticjs and am creating an object from constructor `Rect`. I want the value of the property `draggable` to dynamically change to the value of `optvar` whenever `optvar` changes.

```
Var optvar="true";

rect = new Kinetic.Rect({ 
    x: 22, 
    y: 7, 
    width: 0, 
    height: 0,
     fill: 'red', 
    stroke: 'black', 
    strokeWidth: 4, 
    draggable: optvar    
});

optvar="false"; // I want value if rect.draggable to be equal to false
```

Comment: I assume the Var is a typo and you have var in the real code...

Comment: There's a way to allow using get-ters and set-ters in JavaScript, but beware of browser compatibility. (esp. for IE)

Comment: And similarly that `"true"` and `"false"` are really `true` and `false`.

Comment: adneo: I have multiple objects rect (all created dynamically). I want all objects' property to be linked to one variable. My previous question explains it better http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13757659/kineticjs-when-dynamically-creating-rect-the-rect-behind-it-drags-by-itself#comment18915982_13757659

Comment: Yes few typos there as typing from mobile. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not a basic question. :-)

As of [ES5](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/), it's possible to define properties with *setters* and *getters* via [`Object.defineProperty`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.3.6) (and `Object.defineProperties`). This feature of ES5 is quite broadly supported in modern browsers, but older browsers (such as IE8 and earlier) do not have it.

Using a getter, it's possible to do this:

```
var optvar=true;

rect = new Kinetic.Rect({ 
    x: 22, 
    y: 7, 
    width: 0, 
    height: 0,
     fill: 'red', 
    stroke: 'black', 
    strokeWidth: 4
});
Object.defineProperty(rect, "draggable", {
    enumerable: true,
    get:        function() {
        return optvar;
    }
});
```

That creates a property on `rect` that, when retrieved, returns the current value of `optvar`. It works because the getter function is a closure over the `optvar` variable (more about closures in my blog: [*Closures are not complicated*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/closures-are-not-complicated.html).)

Of course, whether this works correctly with `Kinetic.Rect` will depend on how `Kinetic.Rect` is implemented.

The property created above is enumerable [shows up in `for..in` loops like the others do], but is not writable. If you wanted it to be writable:

```
Object.defineProperty(rect, "draggable", {
    enumerable: true,
    get:        function() {
        return optvar;
    },
    writable:   true,
    set:        function(value) {
        optvar = value;
    }
});
```

From your comment on the question:

> I have multiple objects `rect` (all created dynamically). I want all objects' property to be linked to one variable.

The above mechanism can be used to do that, because of course, you can have getters for all of your rects:

```
var optvar = true;
var rect;
var rects = [];

while (rects.length < 10) {    
    rect = new Kinetic.Rect({ 
        x: 22, 
        y: 7, 
        width: 0, 
        height: 0,
        fill: 'red', 
        stroke: 'black', 
        strokeWidth: 4
    });
    Object.defineProperty(rect, "draggable", {
        enumerable: true,
        get:        getDraggable
    });

    rects.push(rect);
}
function getDraggable() {
    return optvar;
}
```

Now, all 10 of those rects will be draggable, or not, based on `optvar`.

*(Note: I'm assuming all of this code is in a function somewhere, so we're not creating global variables.)*

Comment: Fascinating.  Is there browser-agnostic support for this in a library of some kind (e.g. prototype, underscore, etc...) ?

Comment: @Paul: It's not something that can be shimmed/polyfilled by a library, because it has to be built into the guts of the mechanism for retrieving the value of a property from an object. Some older browsers supported another syntax for getters and setters, but none of the IEs did. The only way to do this with ES3-only browsers is to make `draggable` a function and *call* it whenever you want the value, e.g. `if (rect.draggable())` rather than `if (rect.draggable)`.

Comment: @T.J.: I believe this is a perfect solution and should work. Will test it in my code at the first opportunity. This was not easy as I thought. Thanks ton.

Comment: @user1517108: You're welcome, glad that helped! Do be sure to test on the browsers you want to support, since not all have ES5 features yet.