# Why is my javascript obj not updating in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using angularJS, and have the following controller variables:

```
cont.flag = 0;
cont.obj = {objFlag: cont.flag, objFunction: cont.func};

cont.func = function() {
    // do stuff
}
```

The `cont.flag` variable is bound to user input in the HTML. So when that value changes I want the `objFlag` to update which it is not currently doing. In addition the `objFunction` value seems to always be undefined. Is this because cont.obj is declared above cont.func?

EDIT: If it wasn't clear, the cont.flag variable is correctly being updated by the user input, it's just the pointer to cont.flag in my obj which is not updating. Also, objFunction is not getting populated with the function I pass it.

Here is a bit more information that I provided in a comment about why I have these variables in an object instead of manipulating them directly: So I have a series of functions that I want to chain together, but I want to control which functions get run. So I have an obj for each function: the objFlag which says whether the function should be added to the chain, and objFunction which is the actual function to be run. I wanted a way of associating the objFlag with the objFunction it goes with

Comment: To help you we need at least a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)... or visit the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) for more info.

Comment: Actually, why do you have an `cont.obj` holding the other values in it? Why don't you use `cont.flag` and `cont.func` directly wherever they are needed?

Comment: @lealceldeiro So I have a series of functions that I want to chain together, but I want to control which functions get run. So I have an obj for each function: the objFlag which says whether the function should be added to the chain, and objFunction which is the actual function to be run. I wanted a way of associating the objFlag with the objFunction it goes with

Comment: You should probably try to assign it directly to the object. Something  like: `cont.obj = {objFlag: 0, objFunction: function() { /*do stuff*/ } };` and in the html view use `cont.obj.objFlag` and `cont.obj.objFunction` directly.... but without a reproducible example of your problem it's hard to say.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why `objFlag` is not change along with `cont.flag` has nothing to do with Angular. This is a native Javascript behavior.

This statement:

```
cont.obj = {objFlag: cont.flag, objFunction: cont.func};
```

only assigns an initial `cont.flag` value to `objFlag` and **there is no ongoing link between `objFlag` and `cont.flag`**

This is already explained

- [Javascript - How change object properties without reassign them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46131828/javascript-how-change-object-properties-without-reassign-them)
- [object property to dynamically change with the value of assigned variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13779134/object-property-to-dynamically-change-with-the-value-of-assigned-variable)

Answer (score 0):

Let us think your code in other way

```
cont.flag = 0;
cont.obj = {objFlag: cont.flag, objFunction: cont.func};

cont.func = function() {}
```

which is equivalent to

```js
var cont = {
  flag: 0,
  obj: {objFlag: cont.flag, objFunction: cont.func},
  func: function() {}
}

console.log(cont.obj);
```

You can see the result, undefined `cont` here (Cannot read property 'flag' of undefined"). we can not access variable into another variable within same object.

So, you will think to use `this` here

```js
var cont = {
  flag: 0,
  obj: {objFlag: this.flag, objFunction: this.func},
  func: function() {}
}

console.log(cont.obj);
```

Again you will get undefined values because we can not access object elements with another variable. But we can use function to access them. So last option is to use a getter function for obj to return json with data of other variable into a variable. (in self-referencing json object)

```js
var cont = {
  flag: 0,
  get obj() {return {objFlag: cont.flag, objFunction: cont.func}},
  /*or*/
  /* get obj() {return {objFlag: this.flag, objFunction: this.func}},*/
  func: function() {}
}
console.log("Before change", cont.obj);

//change
cont.flag = 10;

console.log("After change", cont.obj);
```

**UPDATE**

Now, combining your case with above explanation where `cont` is controller's reference, how you can add a getter property in angular controller.

`Object.defineProperty` method is what you need. So your final code will be:

```
cont.flag = 0;
Object.defineProperty(cont, 'obj', {
    get: function() {
        return {objFlag: cont.flag, objFunction: cont.func}
    }
 });

cont.func = function() {}

// you can access obj property to see the values
console.log(cont.obj)
```

Comment: So in this circumstance, cont is not an object, it points to the controller, it is defined like this:
```function myCtrl() {
    var cont = this;
    // rest of code
}```

Comment: @B.Smith eventually it is, `cont = this` means `cont` has reference of current controller's reference which is an object. I have updated answer (see last updated-section) for your need .